# Is there a term to describe a woman that looks at men purely as objects of sex

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, gender-politics

The term "pig" is colloquially used to describe a man that looks at women purely as objects of sex. Is there such a term that describes a woman that looks at men purely as objects of sex?

Comment: i have heard "empowered" used this way before.

Comment: If you're in polite company, you can say, "She's hot to trot." (US)

Comment: "Pig" as an insult is rather broader than that, covering a wide range of undesirable personality traits, mostly tending toward those that might be considered "unrefined".

Comment: @smithkm, point well made.

Comment: I thought most *pigs* today were ***greedy*** people (the *male chauvinist* variety having surely all died of old age by now! :)

Comment: "One of my crazed admirers."

Comment: This has already been covered. Search for  "stud" on EL&U.

Answer (score 2):

*[Man-eater](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=maneater)* might work depending on the context. Also *player*.

Answer (score 2):

If the woman is older and is interested in younger men, then the word **cougar** may be used.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar_%28slang%29):

> Cougar is a slang term that refers to a woman who seeks sexual relations with considerably younger men. ABC News states that these women pursue sexual relations with people more than eight years younger than they are, while The New York Times states that the women are over the age of 40 and aggressively pursue sexual relations with men in their 20s or 30s. However, the term can also refer to any female who has a male partner much younger than herself, regardless of age or age difference.

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cougar):

> (Canada, US, slang) A woman of middle age who actively seeks the casual, often sexual, companionship of younger men, typically less than 35 years old; by implication a female “sexual predator”.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a **Damalidares**, a **mantrap** (slang), a **dominatrix**

Answer (score 0):

sexual predator, or just predator

sexual exploiter

slut

hook-up

loose woman

promiscuous

indiscriminate

looking for anything in pants